# Get over points

Tags: sql, match

I am writing a function to get overall score in SQL

What I have is;

```
out of 20 points I got 12.4 points
```

so if I transform that, to take percentage over 100% how would I do it?

Thanx,
Adnan

Comment: Are you storing that entire string "out of 20 points I got 12.4 points" in your database rather than using 2 numeric columns? Can you post the relevant part of your table definition?

Comment: Which database are you using? MS SQL server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presuming you mean "function" as in stored procedure, it would look like this in Oracle:

```
create or replace function pct
    (p_score in number
     , p_total in number)
    return number
    deterministic
is
begin
    return p_score * (100/p_total);
end;
/
```

Different flavours of database have different specifications for writing stored procedures.

Comment: Hmm, not sure I deserve those rep points, as Adnan awarded them while I completely rewrote my answer, from a SQL query to an sproc.

Answer (score 3):

Divide the points you've got by the total, and multiply by 100:

```
select [got] / [total] * 100
from MyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

(12.4 / 20) x 100 will give the percentage.

So declare a percentage variable in your func, use the above and return that?